# Letter "c" appearing inside pmatrix environment with aastex

Tags: amsmath, matrices, aastex

My journal recently updated its official class file, [`aastex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/aastex), from version 5.2 to version 6.0. Apparently this was a major rewrite, as the journal abandoned its own class and based 6.0 off the ancient third-party `emulateapj` made before the journal published class files.

Now I'm getting an italix "c" at the beginning of my `pmatrix` with the new version. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 \\
    0  & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

With 5.2 I get this:

[image: output from 5.2]

while with 6.0 I get this:

[image: output from 6.0]

Where is this coming from, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: (I would love to post a link to the 5.2 cls file for completeness, but I can't seem to find it hosted anywhere. All the links on the [CTAN archive](http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/pkg/aastex.html) are dead, for example.)

Comment: are you sure it's the right code you posted, because i dont see any 'c' in the code.

Comment: Indeed there is no "c" in the code, which is what makes this so baffling.

Comment: The `c` comes from the internal `array` environment usages. The missing number error you get is from `\c@MaxMatrixCols` (the LaTeX counter `MaxMatrixCols`) which is used internally by `amsmath`. I've found a work-around. I don't understand what `aastex6` changes, though.

Comment: i compiled your code using the document class `article` instead and i got no extra 'c' so it must be from the document class `aastex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the internal usage of the `array` environment by `amsmath`'s `pmatrix`. At some point

```
\array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}
```

is executed which prepares a table with `MaxMatrixCols` columns (default is 10).

(This makes it that you do not have to insert the number of columns in your table/matrix on your own. Some work around it is done to ensure that the parentheses are correctly spaced.)

If one defines `\array{*{\c@MaxMatrixCols}c}` instead, the code snipped works.

I don't know what `aastex6` changes but it uses a lot of `\newcolumntype`s …

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\env@matrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep % taken from amsmath.sty lines 895ff
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*{\c@MaxMatrixCols}c}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 \\
    0  & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the end result is really ugly.

Comment: @egreg Well, you could use `mathtool`s `pmatrix*`, however `aastex6` uses some redefinition of `\begin` which includes a spurious space which screws with `mathtools`s space-aware ifnextchar.

Comment: My impression is that `aastex6` screws up all kind of matrices.